# what does CSS3 transition do?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I stumble upon this code around:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
-moz-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
```

what does this do? can someone please explain further, I don't understand samples on w3schools and MDN. I'd really appreciate

Comment: It transitions all animatable properties with a time-scale of 0.1s and a easing curve of "ease-in". Any animatable properties that change, will do so according to these rules.

Comment: Check this link out https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/ the explanation plus the live examples are easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a transition describes how a css layout will "transition to another layout" to break it down

the first element

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
```

**all** describes which css properties to apply the transition effect to

*The transition-property CSS property is used to specify the names of CSS properties to which a transition effect should be applied.* [mdn transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property)

***0.1s*** describes the duration

**ease-in** describes the type of transition

so `-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;`
this is saying for all css Properties i want a .01 second transition time using the ease-in transition mode
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property)

Comment: Thanks, didn't get it on first look

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio which part was unclear (this way i can make the answer better for everyone else)

Comment: the syntax on samples, it was separately done like { transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 1s; }

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Transitions are basically when the element in the DOM is moving.

For example it would rotate a rectangle div; it could enlarge or stretch the element.

Comment: Is this accurate? What if I change the background color? It wouldn't move then, nor does it have anything to do with the DOM.

Comment: Changing color wouldn't be considered a transition. For example  check out this fiddle http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1 and hover over the red squre & it will strech. This is an example of a transition. Hope this helps!

Comment: That example only transitions the width property... of course you can transition colors. --- proof (http://leaverou.github.io/animatable/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification evolutionxbox. You're right we can transition colors; at the time I wrote that I meant changing the color of a background with css by setting the background-color: property isn't considered a transition.

Comment: I still do know why not. It's a transitional property... `transition-property: background-color`. Which would make changing it a transition.

Comment: Yes something like this I would strongly agree is a transition -- transition: background-color 0.5s ease; however if someone simply just sets the color such as background-color:orange; this would not be a transition. My original comment wasn't clear when I stated changing color wouldn't be considered a transition. Hope that helps clarify what I was trying to say. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying.